# The sum of two numbers equals 318, express the product of the numbers according to the lowest

Tags: arithmetic

I didn't understand the question on the title, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: according to the lowest what?

Comment: That's all the question says, I didn't get it

Comment: well, if we don't know what the question means, I suggest you skip this one and work on a different problem instead.

Comment: And relax a bit; you look really tense in that picture.

Comment: I'm translating it from my language so maybe something got lost there, a more literal translation would be "express the product of the numbers in function of the lowest one"... I will relax ^^

Comment: @Delta: Your comment translation is much better than your title one, fyi. (I would write "Express the product of the numbers **as a** function of the lowest one.")

Comment: a better translation would be " ... in terms of the smaller one".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question says that there are two numbers $x$ and $y$ whose sum is 318. Then it asks you to assume $x<y$ and express $xy$ using only $x$ (that is, without using $y$).

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry, that means $x < 159$ how do I express 318 with only $x$ if $x < 158$

Comment: There is still a piece of information you are not using. Try writing everything you know using equations.

Comment: You mean like $x+y=318; y=318-x;xy=x(318-x);xy=318x-x^2;$ am I on the right path or completely lost?

Comment: You tell me. Are you closer to achieving the task than before?

Comment: I don't know, I was thinking the answer is $f(x)=318x-x^2$. I'm gonna go back to studying sociology I guess

Comment: @Delta: I don't know what $f(x)$ is doing, but if it's supposed to be $xy$, then this is in fact true. But you knew this. All of the manipulations you did were correct, so certainly $318x-x^2$ is an equivalent expression for $xy$. And your final answer did not use $y$, so you have done exactly what the question has asked!

Comment: I guess it makes sense then, except I didn't understand where the info about $x < y$ would influence the equation

Comment: @Delta: Okay! Well, it's good that you don't understand why that matters, because it doesn't; $xy=318y-y^2$ as well. (But that's the sort of information I would have liked to see in your second comment!)